# What is the meaning of `input =input || ' '` when customizing own filters in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I see that when customising our own filter we need to give the data as input for filtering in filter function but inside the function i see like this :
`input = input || ' '`.

**Code**

```
angular.module('myReverseFilterApp', []).filter('reverse', function() {
    return function(input, uppercase) {
        input = input || '';
        var out = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            out = input.charAt(i) + out;
        } // conditional based on optional argument 
        if (uppercase) {
            out = out.toUpperCase();
        }
        return out;
    };
})
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'hello';
}]);
```

Comment: angular.module('myReverseFilterApp', [])
.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(input, uppercase) {
    input = input || '';
    var out = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      out = input.charAt(i) + out;
    }
    // conditional based on optional argument
    if (uppercase) {
      out = out.toUpperCase();
    }
    return out;
  };
})
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'hello';
}]);

Comment: It just means that if input value is null then set it to `''` empty string.

Comment: Thanks Chandermani!!

Answer (score 1):

The point on this is to initialize the input value with empty string if you're input doesn't have a value given as parameter in you're filter.
So basically if you're input from `return function(input, uppercase) {` hasn't a value(e.g. 'dog') , the input will be empty(it will take the empty string value `''`.
So the || is an `OR operator` . It means that if the input is `undefined`, `null` or `0` it will take the second value.
If you have some other questions, shoot :D .

Answer (score 0):

It's purpose to set the default value of input variable in case the value is undefined or null.

You will notice `input.charAt(i)`, if the value of input is null or undefined, reference error would occur because charAt method is a method of a proper string.